# Serving Django Static Content based on DEBUG status

Tags: django

I have recently set up our project to serve static and media files from Amazon S3. This in turn has made our project serve all content from S3 even when working locally.

Our static settings are set to the following to work with S3:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/%s/" % STATIC_S3_PATH
STATIC_URL = '//s3.amazonaws.com/%s/static/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

And in the URLs conf file we have added the following to match the Django documentation:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'),
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'), 
    )
```

Obviously these URL patterns will not work because we are serving files on "//s3.ama...". I thought in my wisdom that I could then write a piece of regex to get around the problem and tried replacing:

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'),
```

with:

```
url(r'//s3.amazonaws.com/%s/static/(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, 'serve'),
```

This didn't work either. So to finally get around the problem I added a conditional statement in the settings file to decided where to serve static files from:

```
if DEBUG:
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '//s3.amazonaws.com/%s/static/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

What do people think of this solution? I'm not really happy with it going forwards. What are my alternatives?

Comment: the conditional in `settings.py` seems perfectly reasonable. why don't you like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional in the settings is a good solution.

Another option is to use a separate settings file for local settings.